# C++ Multi-line comments using backslash

Tags: c++, comments

Can // style comments be continued to the next line by using a back slash, like multi-line macros? E.g.

```
// here is a comment \
   and this is more comments \
const char* x = "hello";  // this line of "code" is actually still a comment
int x = 5; // and now an actual line of code
```

Comment: I realize you already have an answer, but an equally good answer would be "what happened when you tried it?"

Comment: The answer is that the language allows it but please, *don't do it*. Many editors will not pick it up and they will not highlight the next line as a comment, you and others will read the code and expect the next line to be executed... If asking just for fun, try ending single comment line with `??/`, something like: `// What's this ??/`

Comment: Don't do this. I don't even want to know if you can. This sounds like the most evil thing I have seen considered.

Comment: @hobbs: (Yeah, it's an old comment.) "What happened when you tried it" doesn't necessarily answer the question. See my answer; there are cases where g++ IMHO gets this wrong.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes. Lines terminated by a `\` are spliced together with the next line very early in the process of translation. It happens at phase 2 of translation, before comment removal and before preprocessor has a chance to do its work.

Comment recognition and removal takes place at phase 3. For this reason you can turn a `//` comment into what looks like a multi-line comment by using the `\`. This usually fools most syntax-highlighting source code parsers.

Preprocessor works at phase 4.

This all means that you can "multiline" virtually anything using the `\`, including comments and preprocessor directives

```
#\
d\
e\
f\
i\
n\
e \
ABC \
int i

int main() {
A\
B\
C = 5;
}
```

P.S. Please note that the terminating `\` does not introduce any whitespace into the spliced line. This should be taking onto account when writing multi-line comments using the `\` feature. For example, the following comment

```
// to\
get\
her
```

stands for the single word "together" and not for three separate words "to get her". Obviously, incorrect use of `\` in comments might drastically obfuscate and even distort their intended meaning.

Comment: Thanks, I just spent about an hour trying to figure out why both gcc and clang couldn't find a declaration because of this.

Comment: You can use this multi phase mechanism to make optional comments:-
    #define optional_comment /##/                                                       

    optional_comment This is also a comment.

Comment: Note, however, that it's done *after* trigraph translation, so if you want to be *really* nasty, you can continue a line with `??/` instead of a normal backslash...

Comment: @Jerry: Nice - I wonder if you can turn that into something [underhanded](http://underhanded.xcott.com/)...

Comment: You can do just about ANYTHING with the preprocessor.  Including make C/C++ look like BASIC or Pascal.  But that doesn't mean you SHOULD.  Extending comments like that is stupid, unproductive and downright dangerous.  Please do NOT do anything like this in a production environment!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @paulsm4: That's great, but first and foremost this is not a preprocessor feature. Preprocessor features cannot affect comments, because comments are removed from the translation unit before preprocessor has any chance to do anything.

Answer (score 18):

Here's an excellent reason *not* to do this.  The following program prints "This will appear".

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << "This "
    // A comment ... \ 
    << "will appear"
    // Another comment ... \
    << ", but this won't"
    << std::endl;
}
```

Why?  Because the first `\` is followed by a blank, and so it's just part of the comment, *not* a line-splicing character.  The program's behavior can quietly and significantly change due to invisible trailing white space.

An even better reason not to do this: g++ gets it wrong, even with `-pedantic`.  When I compile this program using g++ the output is just "This"; the trailing white space after the first `\` is ignored.  In my opinion this is how it *should* work, but it's not what the language standard says.  (Line splicing happens in translation phase 2.  I suppose one might argue that the trailing blanks could be deleted in phase 1, but I'm not convinced that that's a valid argument -- and I don't know whether the gcc authors have actually made that argument.)  In any case, g++ 4.5.2 and Sun CC version 5.5 disagree with each other.

If you want multi-line comments, either use `/* ... */`, or insert a `//` at the beginning of each line.  I prefer the latter, because it's much easier to tell that a given line is part of the comment.  (Actually it's multiple single-line comments.)  Any decent editor should let you do this without typing `//` N times for N lines.  Or, if you're commenting out a block of code, use `#if 0 ... #endif`.

Comment: moreover some IDEs (like Eclipse, as I just tested) simply trims the trailing space as you save the source file

Answer (score 0):

I originally said "No, you can't".

But I still say "No, you SHOULDN'T"!

Use /*  */ instead.

EXAMPLE:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  // Begin comment \
     continue comment?
  return printf ("Hello world!\n");
}
```

The above compiles, for reasons explained in other posts.  But it's WRONG:

- "//" are INTENDED for single-line comments (you should use "/* */" for nested, and for multi-line comments
- Relying on "\" continuation lines is a great way to inject weird, difficult to debug errors in your program.

Just like eating stringbeans through your nose: even if you CAN, you probably SHOULDN'T.

IMHO...

Comment: That's a valid opinion, but it doesn't really answer what's being asked.

Comment: `/*...*/` comments don`t nest.

Comment: @KT: /* */ comments don't nest - they ALLOW you to nest a comment within a line of code.  AndreyT: "// are INTEnded for..." was a typo.  I deleted the line

Comment: @paulsm4: "@KT" doesn't notify me; "@Keith" would have.  FYI.

Comment: `/*...*/` comments don't nest in the sense that you can't do `/* hi /* there */ pal */`.