# making Advanced Logger code for native andorid, error "expected primary-expression before ',' token"

Tags: android, c++, logging, java-native-interface, printf

hi i am developing new logger for android.
in vc version i used log like this,

---

```
//ref http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487986/file-macro-shows-full-path
  #define CURRENT_FILE_NAME (strrchr(__FILE__, '\\') ? strrchr(__FILE__, '\\') + 1 : __FILE__)

//ref ##VAR things - http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gcc/gcc_44.html
//ref define "" __vars__ something - http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-dev/199710.mbox/%3CPine.LNX.3.95.971028083446.14671A-100000@gaia.vr.net%3E
  #define printfAdv(fmt,...)\
    {\
printf("[%s] " fmt " ... @(%s)[%s:%d]\n",__TIME__,##__VA_ARGS__,__FUNCTION__,CURRENT_FILE_NAME,__LINE__);\
fflush(stdout);\
    }
 #define  LOGV(fmt,...)  \
    {\
printfAdv(fmt,__VA_ARGS__);\
    }
```

---

->[09:59:42] inputting ... @(processInputKey)[vc_input.cpp:63]
and it worked like charm.

but in android, it cannot be built since some error.

---

```
 #define  InternalLoggerv(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)

//ref http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487986/file-macro-shows-full-path
//win for two back slash
#define CURRENT_FILE_NAME (strrchr(__FILE__, '\\') ? strrchr(__FILE__, '\\') + 1 : __FILE__)

//ref ##VAR things - http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gcc/gcc_44.html
//ref define "" __vars__ something - http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-dev/199710.mbox/%3CPine.LNX.3.95.971028083446.14671A-100000@gaia.vr.net%3E
#define printfAdv(fmt,...)\
    {\
InternalLoggerv("" fmt " ... @(%s)[%s:%d]\n",##__VA_ARGS__,__FUNCTION__,CURRENT_FILE_NAME,__LINE__);\
    }

//  fflush(stdout);\
//printf(fmt " ... @(%s)[%s:%d]\n",##__VA_ARGS__,__FUNCTION__,CURRENT_FILE_NAME,__LINE__);\
//printf("[%s] " fmt " ... @(%s)[%s:%d]\n",__TIME__,##__VA_ARGS__,__FUNCTION__,CURRENT_FILE_NAME,__LINE__);\

#define  LOGV(fmt,...)  \
    {\
printfAdv(fmt,__VA_ARGS__);\
    }
```

---

This gives error when LOGV("blah blah"); not when LOGV("%s","blah balhh");
and error says 'expected primary-expression before ',' token'....

what makes this differnt, and how can i use sometihng like in android native deveolopemnt? thatnk you.

Comment: Have a look at the preprocessed source code.

Comment: @PlasmaHH what do you mean.. 'preprocessed source code'?

Comment: printf means 
"
_Check_return_opt_ _CRTIMP int __cdecl printf(_In_z_ _Printf_format_string_ const char * _Format, ...);
"

...
and __android_log_print says
"
int __android_log_print(int prio, const char *tag,  const char *fmt, ...)
#if defined(__GNUC__)
    __attribute__ ((format(printf, 3, 4)))
#endif
    ;
"

Comment: Please [see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059549/c-multi-line-comments-using-backslash). I think that is your problem.

Comment: @JesseGood good link but not my case...

Comment: Ohhh
solved. not calling intermediate function did it.

#define  InternalLoggerv(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#define  LOGV(fmt,...)  \
  {\
 InternalLoggerv("" fmt " ... @(%s)[%s:%d]\n",##__VA_ARGS__,__FUNCTION__,CURRENT_FILE_NAME,__LINE__);\
  }