# Why does my string say (null)?

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to set filename based on condition but it's not working. It keeps saying (null).

```
void main()
{
    int cond = 1;
    char * filename;
    // C:\other\path\here\
    filename = "C:\\other\\path\\here";
    if (cond)
        // C:\some\path\here\
        filename = "C:\\some\\path\\here";

    printf("%s", filename);
}
```

Comment: That's not your real code.

Comment: ` // C:\other\path\here\ ` this makes next line as comment so filename isn't assigned.

Comment: @mohaned - well spotted sir!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059549/c-multi-line-comments-using-backslash

Comment: @nneonneo noo I can't show real code

Comment: Just use `/` for path separator everywhere (including your comments). (Works on Windows, don't worry.)

Comment: @mat thank you i will try that tomorrow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the standard,

```
§2.1.2 [lex.phases]
```

> Each instance of a new-line character and an immediately preceding
>   backslash character is deleted, splicing physical source lines to form
>   logical source lines.

So

```
// C:\other\path\here\
filename = "C:\\other\\path\\here";
```

becomes

```
// C:\other\path\here\filename = "C:\\other\\path\\here";
```

Likewise

```
// C:\some\path\here\
filename = "C:\\some\\path\\here";
```

becomes

```
// C:\some\path\here\filename = "C:\\some\\path\\here";
```

Hence filename never gets initialized.

The MS C++ compiler gives a warning.

> (6) : warning C4010: single-line comment contains line-continuation character
>
> (9) : warning C4010: single-line comment contains line-continuation character

After preprocessing, this will be the code, I think

```
void main()
{
    int cond = 1;
    char * filename;

    if (cond)
        printf("%s", filename);
}
```

Actually, in the above program `filename` can have any value, not necessarily null. So your program could print anything, crash, whatever. You are probably compiling debug & your compiler null initializes unitialized pointers in debug mode & hence you get `null`
Ob: `main` is always `int main` not `void main`