# C++: All Member Functions Give Implicit Definition Error When I Define Operators

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors

I have a number class here that works properly:

number.hpp

```
#ifndef NUMBER_HPP
#define NUMBER_HPP

#include <memory>

class Number
{
private:
     std::unique_ptr<int[]> mDigits;
public:
     // CONSTRUCTORS \\
     Number();
};

#endif
```

number.cpp

```
#include "number.hpp"

#define PRECISION 2048

Number::Number()
    :mDigits( new int[PRECISION]() )
{
}
```

When I add the following operators

number.hpp

```
#ifndef NUMBER_HPP
#define NUMBER_HPP

#include <memory>

class Number
{
private:
     std::unique_ptr<int[]> mDigits;
public:
     // CONSTRUCTORS \\
     Number();

     // CONST OPERATORS \\
     bool operator==( Number const& rhs ) const;
     bool operator!=( Number const& rhs ) const;
};

#endif
```

number.cpp

```
#include "number.hpp"

#define PRECISION 2048

Number::Number()
    :mDigits( new int[PRECISION]() )
{
}

bool Number::operator==( Number const& rhs ) const  
{
    for( int i = 0; i < PRECISION; ++i )
        if( mDigits[i] != rhs.mDigits[i] )
            return false;
    return true;
}

bool Number::operator!=( Number const& rhs ) const
{
    return !( *this == rhs );
}
```

I get the following error from GCC 5.4, GCC 6.2, and CLANG idk

```
number.cpp:5:16: error: definition of implicitly declared constexpr Number::Number()
Number::Number()

error: number.cpp:12 no bool Number::operator==( const Number& rhs ) const member function declared in class Number
```

And so on for every method in the class. What is happening here?

Comment: Shoudln't the signature be `bool operator==(  const Number& rhs ) const;`?

Comment: I just switched them around to see if this way would work. I think they're interchangeable. But neither one works.

Comment: Don't summarize code that isn't working. `//same as before` often hides errors. Post the actual code that shows the error.

Comment: edited number.cpp

Comment: Can you try removing the \\?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public:
     // CONSTRUCTORS \\
     Number();

     // CONST OPERATORS \\
     bool operator==( Number const& rhs ) const;
     bool operator!=( Number const& rhs ) const;
```

The preprocessor removes all occurrences of backslash-newline (i.e. `\` at the end of a line) very early in processing. What you end up with is:

```
public:
     // CONSTRUCTORS \         Number();

     // CONST OPERATORS \         bool operator==( Number const& rhs ) const;
     bool operator!=( Number const& rhs ) const;
```

Which is then parsed as two comments and one declaration,

```
     bool operator!=( Number const& rhs ) const;
```

Solution: Don't use `\` as the last character in a line. Just write `// CONSTRUCTORS` or `// CONST OPERATORS`.

Comment: That's a damn shame, it looks so pretty. Thank you though, my comments are the last place I would have looked.

Comment: @cp420 If you want symmetric comments with decoration at the beginning and end, why not use `/* CONSTRUCTORS */`? :-)

Answer (score 0):

The \\ in your comments starts a multi-line comment (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059549/c-multi-line-comments-using-backslash)).  This causes the declarations of those two functions (the default constructor and operator==) to really be comments in the header file.