# gcc multi line comment warning

Tags: c++, gcc, comments, compiler-warnings

I'm getting a warning

> warning: multi-line comment [-Wcomment]

due to a comment that I have that looks something like

```
// strings can start with a \ and also end with a \
```

I understand the error and have seen other SO messages on the subject.

I can easily fix the warning (by double quoting the \s).

What I'm curious about is that I took care to make sure that the line **does not** end with a \. The line ends with \ and then a space. Is this the preprocessor stripping my trailing space and thereby introducing the warning?

Comment: You might add `...` at the end of the comment, or use `'\'` instead of just \ in it

Comment: just add a character after the final \

Comment: @Indent Fixing the problem is easy, but I'd like to understand what is going on.

Comment: The compiler believes that a line ending with "\" continues on the next line

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059549/c-multi-line-comments-using-backslash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

During the [initial processing](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.1/cpp/Initial-processing.html) preprocessor performs a series of textual transformations on its input.

Here's the quote from the docs (relevant piece is in bold):

> Continued lines are merged into one long line.
>
> A continued line is a line which ends with a backslash, . The backslash is removed and the following line is joined with the current one.
>
> ...
>
> The trailing backslash on a continued line is commonly referred to as a backslash-newline.
>
> **If there is white space between a backslash and the end of a line, that is still a continued line. However, as this is usually the result of an editing mistake, and many compilers will not accept it as a continued line, GCC will warn you about it.**

In this case it is best to use `'\'` instead of `\` as backslash is used as a symbol and not as a continued-line indicator. Another (subjectively inferior) option is to put an ending non-whitespace character after `\` (for example a dot).

Comment: Thanks for the link and the details. For info clang and icc do the same but no warning from MSVC.